# Django ORM: ManyToMany insert

Tags: django, orm

these are my models:

```
class Content(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_(u"Name"), max_length=50)
    recipients = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True)

class Delivery(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_(u"Name"), max_length=50)
    permissions = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True)
    content = models.ForeignKey(Content, null=True)
```

And I'm overriding the save method of Delivery so that when I create a delivery a new Content is created as well:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    is_insert = False
    if self.pk:
        content = Content.objects.get(pk = self.content.pk)
        content.name = 'Delivery: '+self.name
        content.save()
    else:
        is_insert = True            
        content = Content()
        content.name = 'Delivery: '+self.name       
        content.save()                        
        self.content = content

    super(Delivery, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    if is_insert:
        content.recipients.add(self.permissions)                    
        content.save()
```

My problem is that I'm not getting to insert into Content.recipients the same users I have in Delivery.permissions.

How can I do that?
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

What you can try doing is:

```
delivery = Delivery.objects.get(name="some_name")
```

(Just a small side note: remember that Delivery model must have a single object associated with "some_name", otherwise get() will throw an error that 2 objects have been returned)

Now,
`permissions = delivery.permissions.all()`

```
con = Content.objects.get(name="content_name")
```

(same side note applies)

Now simply do: `con.recipients.add(*permissions)`. And if you want to add same permissions to all the Content objects, then you can simply loop through every object of `Content.objects.all()` and do the above `add` operation done above for a single content object.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try iterating over the delivery permissions and adding a content recipient for every permission in the loop.

```
for perm in self.permissions.all():
    content.recipients.add(perm)
    content.save()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried already, i get this error when trying 'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable. I've also tried self.permissions.all(), etc.. so far the don't work

Comment: try `self.permissions_set.all()` see my updated answer

Comment: it doesn't work as well. I've checked if permissions area empty and it is not. I guess there is something to do with the context self.permission must return just after the saving process has ended, something like this.. I just don't know yet

Comment: what traceback are you getting now

Comment: this: 'Delivery' object has no attribute 'permissions_set'

Comment: what about with just `permissions.all()`

Comment: The page doesn't throw error, the permissions in delivery are added but recipients in content are not. This .all() seems to return empty. I've put a print just to check if the for loop is happening and it is not. That's why I think if has something to do with the context i'm using it (inside a model save override)